# capture specific user name for email using regular expression

Tags: regex

I am stuck in validating a regular expression at

http://regexone.com/example/2?

The problem which i am facing is i have to capture a specific user name in email address provided.
Below is a list of emails, and the text to be captured using regular expression :

Email

1. tom@hogwarts.com
2. tom.riddle@hogwarts.com
3. tom.riddle+regexone@hogwarts.com
4. tom@hogwarts.eu.com
5. potter@hogwarts.com
6. harry@hogwarts.com
7. hermione+regexone@hogwarts.com

Text to capture in each email address :

1. tom
2. tom.riddle
3. tom.riddle
4. tom
5. potter
6. harry
7. hermoine

Comment: I have used the following regular expression : 

^([\w.]+)@[a-z]+\.[a-z]{2}?\.?[a-z]+$

But the following emails are not validating :

tom.riddle+regexone@hogwarts.com

hermione+regexone@hogwarts.com

Comment: Its solved ! :-) and the expression i used is : ^([\w.]+).*?@[a-z]+\.[a-z]{2}?\.?[a-z]+$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple regex captures the first unbroken sequence of "word chars or dot":

```
^[\w.]+
```

The breakdown of this regex is:

- `^` start of input
- `[` open a character class
- `\w` a "word char" is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- `.` a literal dot (when inside a character class)
- `]` close character class
- `+` one or more of the preceding expression

Note that (most) chars lose their special meaning inside a character class, so there's no need to escape the dot.

I tested it on the linked site and this works :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but i still didn't understand the exact meaning of it. Can you please illustrate it a bit further, as i am new to regex.

Comment: and what do you mean to "escape the dot" ?

Comment: I have solved the problem using your solution and my regular expression is : ^([\w.]+).*?@[a-z]+\.[a-z]{2}?\.?[a-z]+$

Comment: I have added an explanation of the regex.

Comment: Thanks Bohemian, now i got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
([a-z\.]+)
```

It means capture all small letters and a dot character.

Note: For proper email validation it would require some more stuff, but this will pass the test you linked.

Comment: You don't need to escape the dot

Comment: I know, but I find it to be more consistent to also escape it inside char class, and it's easier to copy or move in and out of char class.

Answer (score 0):

try this please

([0-9a-zA-Z._]+)+?\S*@

it will capture all symbols before + if we have it, or before @ symbol if we dont have any plus symbols here.